# Integrate yammer with SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, yammer

I would like to share post at specific yammer group once approval process completed from SharePoint designer 2010 . 
Is it doable without writing code or its not allowed ?

Comment: To confirm, is this on-prem SharePoint or SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 1):

OK, actually I have a couple answers for either SP Online or on-prem. If Online, you could use the "When a new item is created in SharePoint list and meets certain conditions, post to my Yammer" (https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/services/shared_yammer/yammer/) template in Microsoft Flow.

If SharePoint is on-prem, you could add a final step to the workflow to send an email to your Yammer group. From https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2783933:

> PROCEDURE Posting a message to your home network
>
> If you want to post a message by using email to your home network, you
>   must send an email message to your network's email domain name,
>   followed by @yammer.com. For example, if your domain is contoso.com,
>   send an email message to consoto.com@yammer.com.
>
> Posting a message to your external network
>
> If you want to post a message by using email to an external network,
>   you must send an email message to the network's name in lowercase and
>   without any spaces or punctuation, followed by @yammer.com. For
>   example, if your external network name is Farbrikam Contoso, send an
>   email message to fabrikamcontoso@yammer.com. Posting a message to
>   groups in your network
>
> If you want to post a message by using email to a specific group in
>   your network, you must send an email message to both the group and
>   network names in lowercase, together with a plus (+) symbol in between
>   the names, and without any spaces or punctuation, followed by
>   @yammer.com. For example, to create a post by using email to the Sales
>   Team in the Contoso network, you would send an email message to
>   sales+contoso.com@yammer.com.

Comment: When I test it from workflow it did not work so I test it directly from outlook I send message to e.g. sales+contoso.com@yammer.com but I received automatically reply message with title : "Yammer: Confirm your post" and contain my post then " To confirm and post this message to Yammer, either reply to this message or press the button" so do we have any workaround to send the post to yammer directly  without confirmation .

Comment: Looks like you do have to have the Enterprise license. If you do try the following:   "if your network is upgraded to Enterprise you can configure this by going to >Admin>Design and Configuration > Email Settings there is tick box that says "Require all users in your network to confirm their posts made by email before posting" make sure to uncheck that box to bypass that step." from: https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/176/t/291412

Comment: Thanks @Todd FOR your response but I can not find (Admin > Design and Configuration > Usage) in yammer group settings so is it require specific privileges or its not exist in group settings ?

Comment: Looks like it may have changed slightly. If I go to the Yammer admin center via the Office 365 admin portal, I see it under "Configuration". Looks like they split Design and Configuration into 2 pages. If you don't see that link or that option, you may have different licensing that changes the available options.